# My migration does not work for my testing files

Tags: flyway

I am trying to migrate a testdb for tesitng. Everything else is working and the directory to the migrations is correct. However, it does not seem to be working. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Can anyone help me? When I try to run my tests, I get the following error:

> ```
> `describe("ApiTable", () => {
> let container: StartedTestContainer;
> let flywayContainer: StartedTestContainer;
> let db: Kysely<DB>;
>
>
> beforeAll(async () => {
> Creating a postgres database using testcontainers
> container = await new GenericContainer("postgres")
>       .withExposedPorts(5432)
>       .withEnvironment({POSTGRES_USER: "postgres"})
>       .withEnvironment({POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "password"})
>       .withEnvironment({POSTGRES_DB: "testdb"})
>       .start();
>
> const host = container.getHost();
> const port = container.getMappedPort(5432);
> const username = "postgres";
> const password = "password"; 
> const database = "testdb";
>
>
> Set the database connection details as environment variables
> process.env.DB_HOST = host;
> process.env.DB_PORT = port.toString();
> process.env.DB_USERNAME = username;
> process.env.DB_PASSWORD = password;
> process.env.DB_DATABASE = database;
>
> Start a Flyway Docker container and run migrations against the Postgres container
> flywayContainer = await new GenericContainer("flyway/flyway")
>       .withCommand([
>         "-url=jdbc:postgresql://"+username+":"+password+"@"+host+':'+port+'/' + database,
>         "-user="+username,
>         "-password="+password,
>         "migrate"
>       ])
>       .withBindMounts([{ 
> source: __dirname + '/../../../../../sql', 
> target:"/flyway/sql" 
>       }])
>       .start();
>
> db = new Kysely<DB>({
> dialect: new PostgresDialect({
> pool: new Pool({
> connectionString: "postgresql://"+username+":"+password+"@"+host+':'+port+'/' + database,
>         }),
>       }),
>
>     });
>
>
>   },50000);`
> ```

Comment: Have you missed off the error in your question? I only see your setup not the error you get.

Comment: Also, you don't need to have your user and password set in both Flyway and your JDBC URL. One or the other should be enough.

Comment: here is the remaining of my code:
it('should raise an error if the database is empty', async () => {
    // Assuming there is an "ApiTable" entity/table
    const { countAll } = db.fn;

    const apiTable = db.selectFrom('api').execute();

    if (!await apiTable) {
      throw new Error('Database is empty');
    }
  }, 50000);

Comment: And i am getting the following error:
 FAIL  src/core/database/table/api.table.spec.ts (7.046 s)
  ● ApiTable › should raise an error if the database is empty

    error: relation "api" does not exist

      73 |     const apiTable = db.selectFrom('api').execute();
      74 |
    > 75 |     if (!await apiTable) {
         |          ^
      76 |       throw new Error('Database is empty');
      77 |     }
      78 |   }, 50000);